# Provide context to broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on a simple one alarm application that will notify the user even if the application is not up. I'm in a little bit over my head, so sorry if I seem like a Java noob.

This is following this tutorial here: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/alarm-example-in-android.html?m=1
It doesn't provide much explanation, but it simplifies things down quite a bit.

My problem is providing the context to the broadcastreceiver class. I know that there are other questions out there asking how to do this, and I have read through them. My problem is, I don't know how to clearly pass through the context in a constructor because of how I use the broadcast receiver in the activity class.

Here is what I mean. This is the code that will run when a button is clicked. I have not finished it, so its just a skeleton atm.

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

I need the application context in the AlarmReciever class because I intend to send a notification.
The way that the tutorial has it set up, the AlarmReceiver is used like:

```
AlarmReciever.class
```

I'm not sure how to pass over context, since I don't use a constructor. Am I missing something obvious or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passed the context into your receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;
private PowerManager pm;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    this.context = context;
    pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,TAG);
    wl.acquire();
            //....do your work. 


    wl.release();


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

Simply create an application instance by extending Application class:

```
public class App extends Application{ 

   private static Context mContext;

   @Override public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();

       App.mContext = getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getAppContext(){
       return App.mContext;
   }
}
```

Now, inside your class that needs your context, just do this:

```
// somewhere in your code
App.getAppContext();
```

NOTE: You might have to set the Application attribute in your AndroidManifest xml file and point to your App class!

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! At the moment it is not requiring me to set the attribute in the manifest file, but that may change when I start testing the app. I am slightly confused what I would need to point to the app class. Could you explain a little bit what you mean?

Comment: what I mean is that you could set the name attribute of your application namespace in the manifest file like this android:name=".App" . Try that then see if your issue is solved then let me know